# std::any of std::unique_ptr doesn't work?

Tags: c++, c++20

Please consider the following C++20 program:

```
#include <any>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  std::any a;
  std::unique_ptr<int> x = std::make_unique<int>(42);
  a.emplace<std::unique_ptr<int>>(std::move(x));
}
```

I'm getting:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:7:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::any::emplace<std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<int>&>::type)’
    7 |   a.emplace<std::unique_ptr<int>>(std::move(x));
      |                                               ^
In file included from test.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/any:273:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class _ValueType, class ... _Args> typename std::any::__any_constructible<std::any::_Decay<_ValueType>&, std::any::_Decay<_ValueType>, _Args&& ...>::type std::any::emplace(_Args&& ...)’
  273 |       emplace(_Args&&... __args)
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/any:273:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9/any: In substitution of ‘template<class _ValueType, class ... _Args> typename std::any::__any_constructible<std::any::_Decay<_ValueType>&, std::any::_Decay<_ValueType>, _Args&& ...>::type std::any::emplace(_Args&& ...) [with _ValueType = std::unique_ptr<int>; _Args = {std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >}]’:
test.cc:7:47:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/any:273:7: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::unique_ptr<int>&>’
/usr/include/c++/9/any:288:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class _ValueType, class _Up, class ... _Args> typename std::any::__any_constructible<std::any::_Decay<_ValueType>&, std::any::_Decay<_ValueType>, std::initializer_list<_Up>, _Args&& ...>::type std::any::emplace(std::initializer_list<_Up>, _Args&& ...)’
  288 |       emplace(initializer_list<_Up> __il, _Args&&... __args)
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/any:288:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:7:47: note:   ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’ is not derived from ‘std::initializer_list<_Up>’
    7 |   a.emplace<std::unique_ptr<int>>(std::move(x));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, std::any requires the contained type to be copy-constructible?  So std::any can't hold move-only types?

Comment: ["This overload only participates in overload resolution if std::is_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, Args...> and std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> are both true."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/emplace)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class `std::any` is copyable. Despite its name, it cannot wrap "any" and all types. Specifically, it cannot wrap non-copyable types. `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable. `std::unique_ptr` cannot be stored in `std::any`.

Comment: Time for a proposal to rename `std::any` to `std::almost_any`

Comment: @CoryKramer maybe we can get `std::move` -> `std::actually_not_moving_anything` into the same proposal

Comment: @CoryKramer `std::some` :o)

Comment: Is then the requirement of the contained object to be copy constructible a consequence of `std::any` being copyable? Similar with `std::function` ?

Comment: @ローウ I suspect that it is related. I suppose it may have been possible to specify that copying `std::any` that wraps non-copyable to throw instead, but that's not what the authors chose. There may be other reasons that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Thank you so much. It took me all day to figure this out. This finally explained the problem.